# Read JSON metadata for a token from Solscan

Tags: python, python-requests, solana

I'm using python and trying to read the metadata from a token on solscan.
I am looking for the name, image, etc from metadata.

I am currently using JSON request which seems to work (ie not fail), but it only returns me:

```
{"holder":0}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am doing several other requests to website, so I think my request is correct.
I tried looking at the documentation on https://public-api.solscan.io/docs and I believe I am requesting the correct info, but I dont get it.

Here is my current code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/jsonParsed',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

params = (
    ('tokenAddress', 'EArf8AxBi44QxFVnSab9gZpXTxVGiAX2YCLokccr1UsW'),
)

response = requests.get('https://public-api.solscan.io/token/meta', headers=headers, params=params)

#response = requests.get('https://arweave.net/viPcoBnO9OjXvnzGMXGvqJ2BEgl25BMtqGaj-I1tkCM', headers=headers)

print(response.content.decode())
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sample works:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

params = {
    'address': 'EArf8AxBi44QxFVnSab9gZpXTxVGiAX2YCLokccr1UsW',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.solscan.io/account', headers=headers, params=params)

print(response.content.decode())
```

I use another URL and parameters in my sample: `https://api.solscan.io/account` used instead of `https://public-api.solscan.io/token/meta` and `address` param instead of `tokenAddress`.

Comment: The `params` needed to be jsonfied?

Comment: No, you can use a tuple as in question. But I use another URL and parameters in my sample: `https://api.solscan.io/account` used instead of `https://public-api.solscan.io/token/meta` and `address` param instead of `tokenAddress`.

Comment: It's not my question. Just needed some clarity. I had the same issue. The `params` needed to be `json` in my case.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I have already figured out that is not your question :) Didn't look at nickname :)

Comment: Amazing! Works like a charm. Thank you so much. This has been bugging me for days